# Stripe creating multiple phases in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to create multiple phases using Stripe for a very specific use case. Running the below code using the Stripe Billings API doesn't actually create multiple phases. It only creates a single phase (the last one).

```
$schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
  'customer' => 'cus_HMDwmb8iAV0X7k',
  'start_date' => 'now',
  'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
    'phases' => [
      [
        'end_date' => 1592910720,
        'proration_behavior' => 'none',
        'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => 5000,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => 'prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO',
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'year',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],


    'phases' => [
      [
        'end_date' => 1594850400,
        'proration_behavior' => 'none',
        'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => 6000,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => 'prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO',
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'year',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],


]);
```

A similar request using Curl works fine:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_schedules \
  -u sk_test_xxx: \
  -d customer=cus_HMDwmb8iAV0X7k \
  -d start_date=now \
  -d end_behavior=cancel \
  -d phases[0][plans][0][price_data][product]=prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO \
  -d phases[0][plans][0][price_data][currency]=usd \
  -d phases[0][plans][0][price_data][unit_amount]=1000 \
  -d phases[0][plans][0][price_data][recurring][interval]=year \
  -d phases[0][end_date]=1592043010 \
  -d phases[0][proration_behavior]=none \
  -d phases[1][plans][0][price_data][product]=prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO \
  -d phases[1][plans][0][price_data][currency]=usd \
  -d phases[1][plans][0][price_data][unit_amount]=15000 \
  -d phases[1][plans][0][price_data][recurring][interval]=year \
  -d phases[1][end_date]=1592910720 \
  -d phases[1][proration_behavior]=none \
  -d phases[2][plans][0][price_data][product]=prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO \
  -d phases[2][plans][0][price_data][currency]=usd \
  -d phases[2][plans][0][price_data][unit_amount]=20000 \
  -d phases[2][plans][0][price_data][recurring][interval]=year \
  -d phases[2][end_date]=1594850400 \
  -d phases[2][proration_behavior]=none \
  -d phases[3][plans][0][price_data][product]=prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO \
  -d phases[3][plans][0][price_data][currency]=usd \
  -d phases[3][plans][0][price_data][unit_amount]=35000 \
  -d phases[3][plans][0][price_data][recurring][interval]=year \
  -d phases[3][end_date]=1595851200 \
  -d phases[3][proration_behavior]=none \
  -d phases[4][plans][0][price_data][product]=prod_HMrCxIwor5bbjO \
  -d phases[4][plans][0][price_data][currency]=usd \
  -d phases[4][plans][0][price_data][unit_amount]=21000 \
  -d phases[4][plans][0][price_data][recurring][interval]=day \
  -d phases[4][end_date]=1597021320 \
  -d phases[4][proration_behavior]=none
```

The only difference I see is that on the Curl request I am explicitly passing the phase number.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php call you are specifying the `phases` parameter twice. So only the second `phases` definition is being used to create the subscription schedule. The fix here is to move all the phases under a single array and parameter as follows:

```
$schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'start_date' => 'now',
  'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
    'phases' => [
      [
        'end_date' => 1592910720,
        'proration_behavior' => 'none',
        'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => 5000,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => $product->id,
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'year',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      [
        'end_date' => 1594850400,
        'proration_behavior' => 'none',
        'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => 6000,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => $product->id,
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'year',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
]);
```

> The only difference I see is that on the Curl request I am explicitly
>   passing the phase number.

It's more that you are passing in the phase index in the phases array. You have to be explicit about this in cURL, but in php you can just add each element to an array and the indexes are implied.

Comment: Thank you, it worked exactly as you described. Great explanation aswell.